# Erasing Image in xcode/cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have an image paced on the screen.If the user select the eraser and erase the image,it should be erased.How can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake it? Put a sprite same color as the background over it.. Means a layer on top of the previous sprite..

Answer (score 0):

If it is a CCNode subclass (CCSprite for example) call

```
[myImage removeFromParentAndCleanUp: YES];
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply.But I want like an eraser.Not Removing the whole image.It's just like erasing a particular area of an image.